# date range comparison

Tags: jquery, datetime

I am looking for a way to have a date/time method where I have multiple drop downs

Month/ Day / Year  -- Hour / am/pm

Month/ Day / Year  -- Hour / am/pm

I am looking for maybe a jquery plugin that will take the first row and on update change the bottom row in a range of time. So if I picked 11pm on the first row, it would change "day" and "hour" and "am"

Has anyone found anything close to this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's anything to directly and specifically address your problem, but [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) will certainly help. According to the site, it is:

> Comprehensive, yet simple, stealthy
>   and fast. Datejs has passed all trials
>   and is ready to strike. Datejs doesn’t
>   just parse strings, it slices them
>   cleanly in two.

Comment: How do I set a input to today with this? I want to break it up into the separate select boxes